# Как задать кодировку в nlog c#

Tags: c#, nlog

Прикрутил nlog к своей утилитке. логи записываются в файл json, но при выводе кириллицы в лог записывается что-то типа: 
"Server runtime error: \u0423\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0439"

в NLog.config ничего по поводу кодировки не нашел (или может плохо искал). гугл молчит.

таргет из nlog.config:

```
<target name="logFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}/GMMQ.Server/Logs/${date:format=yyyyMMdd}.json"
        archiveNumbering="Date"
        archiveFileName="${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}/GMMQ.Server/Logs/{########}.json"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        maxArchiveFiles="10"
   concurrentWrites="true">
  <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
    <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
    <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}" />
    <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
    <attribute name="computer" layout="${machinename}" />
    <attribute name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
    <attribute name="thread" layout="${threadid}" />
    <attribute name="exception" layout="${exception:format=shortType,message,method:separator=
:maxInnerExceptionLevel=30:innerExceptionSeparator = INNER EXCEPTION
:innerFormat=shortType,message,method}" />
    <attribute name="category" layout="${event-context:item=category}" />
    <attribute name="data" layout="${event-context:item=data}" encode="false" />
  </layout>
  </target>
```

Собственно вопрос: как задать правильную кодировку для кириллицы в nlog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<target name="logFile" encoding="UTF8"...
```

Ну и поэкспериментируйте со значением encoding

Comment: Верно. [Ссылка на документацию](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/File%20Target).

Answer (score 1):

в соответствующем `target->layout->attribute` поставить `escapeUnicode="false"`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поставить атрибут `encode="false"` у `<attribute name="exception" ...`.

Comment: увы, но не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Пишите в лог сообщения сразу в нужной кодировке. Например в 1251. При извлечении делайте обратную процедуру.